# How to check if listbox is empty?

Tags: delphi, listbox

I want to do a check on a ListBox if it is empty, like:

```
if {Listbox.Items is empty} then
begin
  Listbox.Items.Add('Item');
end else
begin
  //do somthing else
end;
```

The part of the check if Listbox.Items or if Listbox are/is empty is a little hard for me. I tried to figure out a way how to do it, but I failed as I am still a beginner with Delphi. How can I implement that in Delphi XE5?

Comment: What about `if listbox.items.count = 0`?

Comment: iam not sure why some one give a vote down for this question.

Comment: A downvote can me "doesn't show any research effort". Perhaps someone felt that you didn't read the TListBox method and attribute documentation?

Comment: i mentioned that iam very beginner  in Delphi each question i post it may have some odd and weird points for experts and i learn from each question i post from comments and answers as i learned from you about check count of list box  and also from answer of LeleDumbo  but any how the question is answered and i  learned ,,that the good part .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if listbox.items.count = 0 then
  // it's empty
```

Comment: More precise is just [`Count`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.Count) since it will tell you the count of items also for list box in virtual mode.

Answer (score 1):

In Access VBA there is no ".items.count" property on a Listbox

I tried Me.ListBox.ListCount and .ListIndex to see if the List was empty.

ListCount was always 1 and ListIndex always -1 whether the list was empty or not (in my case).

To overcome that I used:

```
If Me.ListBox.ItemData(0) = "" then
    Do Something
End If
```

This worked for me - hope this helps someone

Comment: This does not answer this question, which has the Delphi language tag. Maybe you can find a similar VBA question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would reverse your if statement.
Personally I like the most code in the true part of my statement and the shorter code in the false part. For some reason it makes more sense to me.

So the code would look like:

```
If Listbox.items.count > 0
begin
  //Do something else
end
else
 Listbox.items.add('item');
```

Also if your true, or false, part only contains 1 line of code you don't need a begin..end. It's not wrong to have them but in my opinion it makes code easier to read if they aren't there ;)

Comment: This is for 10% a copied previous answer, and for 90% a code style opinion. I'll flag it as _not an answer_, because this should be a comment to the question.

Comment: I would **personally** use `if (Listbox.Items.Count > 0) then` instead of `If Listbox.items.count > 0 begin` (`then` is still needed in Pascal) ;)